# writeToFile stucks when the downloading starts

Tags: iphone, function, download, writetofile

When I download some file from url with Objective C function writeToFile my iPhone and iPhone Simulator stucks until file is downloaded how to prevent that ?

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
if(data){
    NSString *saveStringPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/%@.mp3", stringPath, songNameField.text];
    BOOL status = [data writeToFile:saveStringPath atomically:NO];}
```

Comment: At a minimum the download needs to be off the main thread, the easiest way is to use `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`. If you need to write it to a file consider using `NSStream`.

Comment: can you show me how this functions works because I am newbie ?

Comment: Search SO for `sendAsynchronousRequest`, there are dozens of examples.

Comment: I already search but I don't know how to integrate it with my code...